# My Website is redirecting to google search

Tags: php, apache

Since morning morning when I go to my website its redirecting to google search and I haven't updated anything from the website.

Keeps on redirecting to `https://www.google.com/search?q=hotlinking`

Is this a server setting error or a virus?

Please help

Comment: Some additional informations? Page, source?

Comment: Give us more information... how can you expect us to "guess" what your infrastructure is.

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Google today resigned from autosearch while writing in input search, maybe it is a reason why something broke in your site?

Comment: Sorry about that I posted this question when I was panicking.

Comment: This was caused by a hosted js file. Somehow they removed all the code and put `window.location.href="https://www.google.com/search?hotlinking"` from this library `https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.1.1/lib/moment.min.js`

Answer (score 0):

To anyone having the same issue in the future, download all the libraries you need on your server.

What happened today: for new version of fullcalendar 3.4, they putted a redirect link to anyone using their librairies:

https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-3.2.0/fullcalendar.min.js

-> https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-3.4.0/fullcalendar.min.js